# what happens to MS Office if I install W10?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have an Acer Aspire Windows 8.1 and concerned about upgrading. I am an old non-technical person so this may sound like a dumb question to the younger generation. Do i get to keep my MS Office software or will this get deleted?  If so do I need to buy a new MS office for windows 10? I know the files are deleted but what about the software? thank you

Comment: I don't think any software would get removed in an upgrade, though sometimes there could be slight chance that they somehow doesn't work after an upgrade, and reinstallation might be necessary. You don't have the installation source of Office with you?

Comment: You have Office installed on Windows 10?

Comment: I have MS Office installed in Windows 8.1 thank you @Ramhound .

Comment: @TomYan I will need to ask my daughter who is in the UK as she installed this for me before her trip. what does the installation source look like please?  Sorry I am not familiar with technology.

Comment: You asked what would happen if you upgrade to Windows 10 with Office installed, the answer, you would have a Windows 10 installation with Office installed

Comment: @Ramhound thank you kindly for your reply.  With that I will be brave enough to upgrade. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Let's clarify some things to help put your mind at ease:

If you perform a *Windows 10 Upgrade* of Windows 8.1, Microsoft Office should be left alone and continue to work just fine. While not all applications are guaranteed to work when doing an upgrade, the vast majority of them will continue working just fine. I was thoroughly surprised when I did my first upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 how much of my system was untouched and continued to work just as it had before. Your user files/documents *should* be left alone when doing an upgrade, but I always take a backup of them just to be safe.

If you are performing a *clean install of Windows 10* or a *fresh install of Windows 10*, this will erase your existing files and applications. You will need to back up your files and reinstall your applications.

To reinstall Microsoft Office, you need two things:

- Microsoft Office Installation Media

  This is the CD or download which actually contains the Office software required to install office.
- Microsoft Office License Key

  This is the key (like `XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`) which authorizes you to use a particular version of office. This is what you pay for, and as long as you have your key, you can reinstall Office if it ever gets deleted or corrupted. You can obtain the installation media for free or very cheaply if you lose it, but your key cannot be replaced without buying a new copy of Office.

Comment: I upgraded a win 7 pc with office 2k3 on it and it worked just fine.

Comment: @ Darth Android I do not know what a clean or fresh install is, sorry this must be frustrating for you technical folks. It's too difficult for old me. Maybe I will back up manually on a USB stick.

Comment: @Keltari thank you.  If your Office2003 works after the upgrade then perhaps mine will be ok. My daughter bought this computer so we can talk over skype while she is away. I am afraid if something bad happens to the computer I cannot keep in touch.